# Meteor Geolocation method from Event

Tags: meteor

I want to get the latLng, but only after an event.  How can this be achieved?  I've tried tracker and the like but nothing has worked.  The only thing that has worked is calling Geolocation.latLng(); from inside the helper, which is before the event.

Here is how I wish it would work.  I've tried the same thing with Session.set() and Session.get()).  I've also tried to use Tracker dependencies, but since the location isn't available immediately triggering the changed() doesn't help.

I should include that I'm using the package created by the Meteor Development Group located at https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/.

```
var location = {};

Template.Home.helpers({
  'location': function() {
    return location;
  }
);
Template.Home.events({
  'focus .location': function() {
    location =  Geolocation.latLng();
  },
});
```

Comment: what's `Geolocation`? where is it defined? Are you using a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `location` is not reactive variable itself.

```
var location = new ReactiveVar();

Template.Home.helpers({
  'location': function() {
    return location.get();
  }
);
Template.Home.events({
  'focus .location': function() {
    location.set(Geolocation.latLng());
  },
});
```

Don't forget to include reactive var package

> meteor add reactive-var

## But, since you are using mdg:geolocation

And [here](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:geolocation/README.md) API Doc says that every method is reactive, you can use tracker in `onRendered` callback whatever the location changes

```
    Template.Home.onRendered(function(){
      this.autorun(function(){
         location.set(Geolocation.latLng());
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @ZuzEL's answer, but in case you really want to do it your way with Sessions:

```
Template.Home.helpers({
  'location': function() {
    return Session.get("location");
  }
);
Template.Home.events({
  'focus .location': function() {
    Session.set("location", Geolocation.latLng());
  },
});
```

no need for the ReactiveVar package because Sessions are like global reactive themselves :)

Comment: I was trying exactly this and don't believe it works - I'll get back on that.