# How do I effectively store position of users when they submit a post in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation

Im using mdg:geolocation package. 
Im trying to store a users location the moment he or she submits a message.

**In postSubmit.js (client side):**

```
Template.postSubmit.events({'submit form': function(e) {e.preventDefault();
    var post = {
      message:  $(e.target).find('[name=message]').val(),
      loc: {
        type:"Point",
        coordinates: [82.1, 55.4] //fake data 
      }
    };
```

Also I need lines to retrieve the user's current position when he submits the message.

```
Template.postSubmit.onCreated(function() {  
  'loc': function() {                     //doesnt work, identifier error
      Session.set("loc", Geolocation.latLng());
  },
```

**I saw examples touting this version instead but it gives me errors** 
[Meteor Geolocation method from Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497274/meteor-geolocation-method-from-event)

My question is 
 1. how to I replace the fake data to update with the retrieved {lng, lng}?
 2. would the template.onRendered example be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to store it in the session if you only need it when posting messages. You only need to get it in your submit event.

```
Template.postSubmit.events({'submit form': function(e) {e.preventDefault();
  var loc = Geolocation.latLng();
    var post = {
      message:  $(e.target).find('[name=message]').val(),
      loc: {
        type:"Point",
        coordinates: [loc.lng, loc.lat]
      }
    };
    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function (err, res) {
      if (!err)
        console.log("inserted!");
    });
  }
});
```

---

**If you want geolocation to be available throughout the posting process**, easiest is to use polling and a Session variable:

```
Template.postSubmit.onCreated(function() {  
  this.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    Session.set('location', Geolocation.latLng());
  }, 2000); // get location every 2 seconds
});
```

Then, you can retrieve it using a template helper:

```
Template.postSubmit.helpers({  
  'loc': function () {
    return Session.get('location');
  }
});
```

You can stop the interval when the post submission is achieved:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({'submit form': function(e, t) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var loc = Session.get('location');
    var post = {
      message:  $(e.target).find('[name=message]').val(),
      loc: {
        type:"Point",
        coordinates: [loc.lng, loc.lat]
      }
    };
    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function (err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        Meteor.clearInterval(t.interval);
        console.log("inserted!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Would you happen to also know how to turn on detection of geolocation upon say..the opening of the form to type the message and switch off after submission?

Comment: Thanks! Your awesome. Im asking as Im concerned about exhausting battery through constant fetching of coordinates. Is the server side code required? I intend to sort messages by distance of stored message to users current location.

Comment: Theres an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of null` which means loc gives a null value. But then, loc is already defined ...hmm.

Comment: When geolocation doesn't work (GPS not on, unable to locate, etc), it will return `null` instead of a location object. You will have to decide on the behavior you want your app to have in that case.

Comment: You cannot get Session variables from the server. You have to retrieve them on client side and send them to your method.